# Are identification questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I am trying to develop a reboot of a very old game.

Can I ask a questions here asking others to help me identify certain elements of that game?

For example, can I ask to identify a font name (exact or as close as possible) use in that game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For identification questions, be sure you're bringing them to folks who are experts in the thing you want to identify.

In this example, what you want to identify is a font, so you want to talk to experts in typography: folks with wide knowledge of different fonts, and the techniques and tools/resources to track them down.

Those experts would be graphic designers, not necessarily game developers. The fact that the font appeared in a game is incidental, and probably doesn't give a game programmer or character modeller the insight you need into the font's source. So the audience here at GameDev.StackExchange might not be the best folks to ask.

[The Graphic Design StackExchange has a page of guidelines about how to write font identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083/71185) that they'll work with, so that could be a good place to start.

On another note, if your plan is to build on the IP of an old game you did not make and don't presently hold the legal rights for, you may want to read: [Can I remake a game and freely distribute it? Or at least privately keep the remake?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/202225/39518) You may find it safer, legally, to make something that is an *homage* or *spiritual* successor, *inspired* by that game, but not exactly replicating specific identifiable aspects like its fonts or other assets.